# Guidelines for including multiple <script>

Tags: javascript, html, include

What is the recommended best-practice for breaking up and including multiple  files?

It makes sense for me to break up scripts into their own .js files in a /modules/.. folder. In a sort of OOP mentality that separates functionality. However, this causes more http requests to my web host.

Each one is only a few kb. Is it noticeably inefficient to have multiple  files? I also looked into [head.js](http://headjs.com/) and [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) but it seems like over-kill.

*Basically, is it considered a bad practice to divide up javascript into separate files and load them individually, or is there a better method?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast answer to this question.  Each developer or team of developers will find something that works best for them.

Personally, I break up script files into logical chunks for development.  When it comes to deploying the application, I combine and minify all scripts into a single file (I'm a ASP.NET MVC guy so I use their bundling mechanism in version 4 for that).

Answer (score 0):

Basicly there is not a lot of difference between the two options. Just don't forget to add the script tags just before the end of your body tag for the sake of performance and keep programming as you like.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to web, maintainability usually trumps raw speed. What this means is, you're probably better off including 5 or 6 JS files than 1 if that makes your code more maintainable.

Of course, if on the production side, you really need to make every clock cycle and every KB of bandwidth count, you can minify your JS, CSS and PHP in order to make that happen. Most of us don't really need this level of performance even on production sites, so we stick with what's more maintainable and easier to update.